# draw on top of google map with fingertip

Tags: android, google-maps

i am currently doing an android application which contains a google map and i want to draw on top of the map using fingertip motion . pls help me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/myGMap"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:apiKey="0TToqyhMYWcvDuJ5NvNtgc-kB8gljGrTXPgiaqw"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:enabled="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a RelativeLayout instead of a LinearLayout. That will give you the ability to stack a SurfaceView over the  MapView. In the event handlers for SurfaceView, you can write code to detect fingertip motion.
Check [Place a transparent surface view over a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800776/place-a-transparent-surface-view-over-a-map)